# HTML + CSS using 2 images for background

Tags: html, css

I have a header image with a width of `30px`. I have 1 for left and 1 for right. Using 1 image is easy:

```
background: #191919 url(clubzz/balk.png) right no-repeat;
```

The `background-color` is `#191919`, the image `url()`, move it to the right and don't repeat the image, that's easy. But now for left AND right, is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the background css3 to accomplish this.

```
.yourclass {
   background: url("yourpic.jpg") , url("otherpic.jpg");
   background-color: #191919;
   background-position: 25% 25% , 25% 25%;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use background-repeat  property and play with the values of background-position accordingly.

try this:

```
.header{
height:400px; 
background: url(https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png), url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/24/Yahoo!_logo.svg);
background-color: #191919;
background-position: 10% 25% , 90% 25%; 
background-repeat:no-repeat; 
background-size:40%"
```

}